# Single Sign On For Web-pages

Tags: php, authentication, web, autologin

I have researched this problem but it is mostly from people who want to login to sites like google or facebook with a single click.

Here is my problem:

I have two sites. Both sites have their own login pages ( ie login.php). Both sites have usernames in common. I have control over both sites ( I can change their code). 
I want to log in to server B when the user clicks on a link on server A.

I have thought about making one server send a post request to the other but then the other server will create a session with this server instead of with the client's computer.

What I wanted to do was create a proxy login page that communicates with the current login script.

If possible I need this done in php.

Any Suggestions/Ideas/Links?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at what [Wikimedia](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aCentralAuth) does with [Single User Login](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aCentralAuth).

The way the system works is when you log into a project, a token is created and stored in a shared database. That token is then put into the login success page, via an image. For example, this HTML will cause a request to the meta project:

```
<img src="http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:AutoLogin?token=TOKENTOKENTOKEN" alt="meta.wikimedia.org" title="meta.wikimedia.org">
```

The user then makes a request with that token attached to the image, which causes the resulting project to authenticate that user and give the user cookies for that domain.

Comment: The fourth line on your linked page states that CentralAuth does not provide a solution to Single Sign on, or am I misinterpreting the sentence( I am not natively english speaking so this is highly possible)

Comment: @Chaosekie that bit is talking about [$wgSharedDB](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgSharedDB), not CentralAuth.

Comment: Ok thanks, So I should send a token to the user and the user use that token to send a login request to the other server? I should store this token somewhere on the page and with js extract it and use it in a new request? But what should I encode into this token to secure it from another user intercepting it and using it to log into the remote server?

Comment: @Chaosekie You'll need to store the token in a database or have some mechanism to retrieve the token between sites (HTTP request using a shared secret perhaps). That token however should link back to the user, through their identifier and also the current IP address of the session. The token itself can be anything really, as long as it's hashed and changes for each request. As long as you check the IP address you should be good against most requests, however if you're concerned implementing HTTPS is the way to go there.

Comment: Thank you, you have saved me! 12:07 AM here. I will implement all this tomorrow.